# I have a question related to Python Datatype ... String?

Tags: python-3.x

while I was using string I just come across with the following code

```
Variable ="Earth revolves around the sun."
print(Variable[-24:-16])
print(Variable[-4:-1])
```

OUT PUT
revolves
sun
but the out put is not in string
when I use this syntax it gives no string

```
Variable ="Earth revolves around the sun."
Variable[-24:-16]
Variable[-4:-1]
```

shows no output
is there anyone who can guide me about this

Comment: Where are you running this code?

Comment: The print is there to actually show you the output, if you are using an editor which runs all the code at once you can't see what you are giving as an output

Comment: I am using visual studio code (code editor)

Comment: "shows no output is there anyone who can guide me about this" You never do anything that *should* create an output, e.g. `print`, so of course, there is no output

Answer (score 0):

The sub strings ( revolves, sun ) extracted form the string ( Earth revolves around the sun. ) are string only.

you please check the **type()** function to check the datatype of the substring

```
Variable ="Earth revolves around the sun."
Variable[-24:-16]
Variable[-4:-1]

type(Variable[-24:-16])
type(Variable[-4:-1])
```

both will return

```
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
```